# Are you able to subtract in JSON?

Tags: json

Here is my JSON code.

```
{
"user_email": "{User.Email}",
"activity_date": "{Lead.LastAction.Date}",
"record_id": "{Lead.Id}-{Lead.LastAction.Date}",
"action_type": "{Lead.LastAction}",
"milestone": "{Lead.Milestone}",
"date_added": "{Lead.Date}"
}
```

Is it possible to add calculations in the code?

For example, can I add a line where the date_added is subtracted from activity_date?

Comment: Json is not a programming language. So, no.

Comment: I'm also not understanding what you are trying to do with JSON. JSON is a human-readable string representation of data. What programming language are you using?

Comment: YAML is more human-readable than JSON - be like YAML :)

Answer (score 2):

No: JSON is a way to transport JS Objects.

You can do that while you format the JSON in your native language ( for example in PHP or JS serverside), basically creating the JSON object with the result of the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

In JSON just by itself you cannot do that, it's just a data format, it's totally passive, like a text file. (If you happen to use JSONP, then the story would be a bit different, it might be possible, but using JSONP to do such things would step into area of 'hack/exploit' and it probably should not be used in that way:) )

However, I see you are using not only JSON - there is some extra markup like `{User.Email}`. This is totally outside JSON spec so clearly you are using some form text-templating engine. These can be quite intelligent at times. Check that path, see which one you are using, see what are its features, maybe you can write a custom function or expression to do that subtraction for you. Maybe, just maybe, it's as easy as

```
"inactivity_period": "{Lead.LastAction.Date - Lead.Date}"
```

or

```
"inactivity_period": "{myFunctionThatIWrote(Lead.LastAction.Date, Lead.Date)}"
```

but that all depends on the templating engine.